# Android: How to add a canvas into a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a Canvas that draws and edits an image into my FrameLayout.

DrawMap.java extends View and includes my onDraw(Canvas c).
First I'm trying to call this method every time the onLocationChanged is called. This means that the Canvas needs to be recalled/updated. How do I do that?

Here's the other thing. I'm trying to add the Canvas with the pic into my FrameLayout. The Bitmap is drawn by:

```
c.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, newX, newY, paint);
```

Here's the stuff that crashes my app and should add the canvas into the Frame:

```
DrawMap d = new DrawMap(this);

FrameLayout frame_map = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_map);
frame_map.addView(d);
setContentView(frame_map);
```

I'm using two FrameLayouts to split the screen. The left one (frame_map) should display a map, the right one (frame_info) displays relevant information (which works fine).

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is `setContentView(frame_map);`. If `frame_map` is the child of a parent view, you must pass frame_map's parent view as the parameter for `setContentView(View view);`.

This is only a derived guess from a simulation of your code. Thus, I require some additional information from your error report to provide a definite solution.